# Detect if "delete" button on iOS keyboard is pressed in empty UISearchBar

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I am wondering if there is a way to detect when user press <kbd>delete</kbd> button or try to erase character in `UISearchBar`? I searched for quite a bit on Google and I tried couple of solutions where one put a `whiteSpaceCharacter` in the empty `UITextField` and the other use `shouldChangeTextInRange` delegate to do.

The one with empty space, the user can somehow know that there is a space there by just press hold and highlight the space so I think that was not a very good solution.

The one that use `shouldChangeTextInRange` does not work when the search bar is empty.

Another thing to note is that majority of the solutions I found was in Objective C and it would be great if there are some way I can do this in Swift. Or would be great if anyone can point me to the right path.

Comment: add in shouldChangeTextInRange return true when string characters count == 0

Comment: why do you want to detect delete when searchbar is empty?

Comment: @Ramkumar I'm sorry if I misunderstood your comment and I'm relatively new to iOS. If I am understanding correctly, shouldChangeTextInRa‌nge will only be called when the text changed. However, when the text is empty and "delete" is pressed, the text doesn't really change and it will not get called?

Comment: @hariszaman I'm working on a tag based search bar that will function similar to that of stackoverflow keyword entry box. When keyword is entered it turn into label and the textbox is reset to "" that is why I need to detect delete on empty searchbar so that I can delete those label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why you would wan't do delete when the searchBar is empty, but you can do it like this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate{

private var search : UISearchBar!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    search = UISearchBar()
    search.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)
    search.delegate = self

    self.view.addSubview(search)
}

func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    let  char = text.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    let isBackSpace = strcmp(char, "\\b")

    if (isBackSpace == -92) {
        print("Backspace was pressed")
    }
    return true
}

func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchText == "" {
        search.text = " "
    }
}



}
```

This takes use of the UISearchBarDelegate, and finds out if backspace is pressed, via the shouldChangeTextInRange function. If the string is empty, it reapplies a whitespace to make it continuously deletable. It's kinda tacky, but the only way I know of to do it, as it doesen't register when the field is empty otherwise.

Hope it's of any use.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, thanks for your answer. It does work.
One problem I have is that it leave the blank space so when user actually long press in the `UITextField` the space can actually be highlighted.

I guess the only clean way is to make my own `UISearchBar` from `UITextField` so that I can override the `deleteBackward` method to run my own delegate.

I really appreciate your help regardless